# bdate_range AttributeError

Tags: python, pandas

The following lines give AttributeError: `'module' object has no attribute 'bdate_range'`.

I think this might have something to do with a circular reference; but, I don't know where.

```
import pandas as pd

times = pd.bdate_range(start=pd.datetime(2012,11,14,0,0,0),
                       end=pd.datetime(2012,11,17,0,0,0),
                       freq='10T')
```

This is the traceback:

```
AttributeError              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-1eb62db1246d> in <module>()
       4 
       5 
 ----> 6 times = pd.bdate_range(start=pd.datetime(2012,11,14,0,0,0),end=pd.datetime(2012,11,17,0,0,0),
 freq='10T')
       7 filtered_times = [x for x in times if x.time() >= time(9,30) and x.time() <= time(16,20)]
       8 prices = randn(len(filtered_times))

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'bdate_range'
```

Comment: what version of pandas are you on?

Comment: @ChangShe  I think it's 0.7.3. Do you recommend another? Would that require this to be uninstalled? Thanks.

Comment: @user1374969 Yes, use the [latest release](http://pandas.pydata.org/) :). This works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `bdate_range` function was [**introduced in pandas version 0.8.0**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.8.0/whatsnew.html?highlight=bdate_range). *So this ought to work fine if you upgrade to pandas >= 0.8.0 (and I would recommend using the latest stable release).*

*Note: The [pandas website](http://pandas.pydata.org/) allows you to search the docs by version number (select your versions's docs on the right-hand side of the [main page](http://pandas.pydata.org/)). In version 0.7.3 there are [**no search results** for `bdate_range`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.7.3/search.html?q=bdate_range&check_keywords=yes&area=default).*

#### For the latest features and bug-fixes, keep your favourite Data Analysis library up-to-date!